# Thread in [WAITING] state while instantiating new char

Tags: java, multithreading

I've recently stumbled upon a bug that I can't quite explain:

A thread is in a `[WAITING]` state while seems to be executing `char buf[] = new char[count + otherLen];` inside `java.lang.String.concat(String.java:2021)`.

This is the stacktrace:

```
"WORKER3"/[WAITING]
    java.lang.String.concat(String.java:2021)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:357)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    [...]
```

Now, from the [Oracle JDK7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) documentation we can see that a thread in `WAITING` state is:

> Thread state for a waiting thread. A thread is in the waiting state
>   due to calling one of the following methods:
>
> ```
> Object.wait with no timeout   
> Thread.join with no timeout   
> LockSupport.park
> ```

But the source code of `String.concat` doesn't seem to use any of this:

```
 2016       public String concat(String str) {
 2017           int otherLen = str.length();
 2018           if (otherLen == 0) {
 2019               return this;
 2020           }
 2021           char buf[] = new char[count + otherLen];
 2022           getChars(0, count, buf, 0);
 2023           str.getChars(0, otherLen, buf, count);
 2024           return new String(0, count + otherLen, buf);
 2025       }
```

I have a feeling that this could be correlated to garbage collection but I can't find any evidence of such correlation.

Can anybody shed some light on it?

Comment: Thread stacks should not be observed at just one instance of time. Multiple snapshots of thread-dumps should be collected and then analysed that if a thread is waiting for some resource for quite some time. Or is there is a deadlock, A thread waiting at just one point of time is normal.

Comment: @Timothy Are you suggesting that the documentation in OpenJDK is wrong? If so, what other condition may have a thread in WAITING?

Comment: @snovelli : Not at all, no I am not suggesting that doc is wrong. I have said that thread can be waiting at one instance of time, that does not mean it is an issue.
From docs
--------------
A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to perform a particular action. For example, a thread that has called Object.wait() on an object is waiting for another thread to call Object.notify() or Object.notifyAll() on that object. A thread that has called Thread.join() is waiting for a specified thread to terminate.
-----------------